# function from a module not imported in python

Tags: python, function, module, call

Good evenning guys,

I ve got that weird behavior. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a function from a module called tankython, calling a function from a module called usual. However, it looks like Python refuses to recognize the function. Here is the code

```
#tankython.py

from usual import * 
from get_data import *
from settings import *
from actif_class import * 

def tanking(list_spreads,settings):    
####    Tanking    ####  
    fenetre = settings.fenetre    
    list_spread_exit,list_spread_temp= [],[]

    ii= 0       
    for spread in list_spreads : 
        avc = ii * 100/float(len(list_spreads))
        print "Be patient. Tanking in progress..." , avc,"%"
        info = tankython (list_spreads,fenetre,ii) 
        list_spread_temp.append(info)
        ii = ii + 1
    list_spread_exit = check_list(list_spread_temp)

    return list_spread_exit

#usual.py

def check_list(list_entry):
    i = 0
    while i < len(list_entry):
        if list_entry[i] == 0 :
            list_entry.pop(i)
        else : 
            i = i+ 1
    return list_entry
```

Here is the error message which I found really weird as I asked Py to import everything from usual.py:

```
File "tankython.py", line 77, in tanking
  list_spread_exit = check_list(list_spread_temp)

NameError: global name 'check_list' is not defined
```

One last thing: eventually, if I put the function in tankython module, then Py accepts to goes through the entire process. However I really would like to know if there is anything I am doing wrong here.

Cheers guys

Comment: Is there an [`__all__`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) variable in `usual.py`?

Comment: Are you importing the right `usual.py`? In `tankython.py`, add `import usual` then `print usual.__file__`.

Comment: @rawing No there is no such things

Comment: @tdelaney It returns usual.pyc

Answer (score 2):

Try to put file tankython.py and usual.py in the **same folder** and use the

```
from usual import check_list
```

instead of

```
from usual import *
```

May help.
Or you can try:

```
import usual
```

Then change code like:

```
usual.check_list()
```

And

```
from module import *
```

is not a good way to import something if two packages have the same name functions.

Comment: the problem is, I need to import other stuff from this module.
I tried just to see . It now says that it cannot import check_list. Very very strange.

Answer (score 0):

I find another solution, although it is not the most elegan one, especially because it did not explain what went wrong. However, I renamed the entire module usual by f_usual and it is working perfectly fine.

Thanks for your help